# Spring @MVC and @RequestParam validation

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I would like to use the @RequestParam annotation like so:

```
@RequestMapping
public void handleRequest( @RequestParam("page") int page ) {
   ...
}
```

However, I want to show page 1 if the user fiddles with the URL parameters and tries to go to page "abz" or something non-numerical.  Right now, the best I can get Spring to do is return a 500.  Is there a way to override this behavior cleanly without having to take in the parameter as a String?

I looked at the @ExceptionHandler annotation, but it doesn't seem to do anything when I set I use `@ExceptionHandler(TypeMismatchException.class)`.  Not sure why not.

Suggestions?

P.S. Bonus question: Spring MVC is called Spring MVC.  Is Spring MVC with annotations just called Spring @MVC?  Google treats them as the same name, which is annoying.

Comment: Did you try to assign a default value for the variable. @RequestParam has a facility for this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since Spring 3.0, you can set a `ConversionService`. `@InitBinder`'s `value` specifies a particular parameter to apply that service to:

```
@InitBinder("page")
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    FormattingConversionService s = new FormattingConversionService();
    s.addFormatterForFieldType(Integer.class, new Formatter<Integer>() {
        public String print(Integer value, Locale locale) {
            return value.toString();
        }

        public Integer parse(String value, Locale locale)
                throws ParseException {
            try {
                return Integer.valueOf(value);
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    });
    binder.setConversionService(s);
}
```

Comment: Whenever `binder.setConversionService(s)` is called, the exception `java.lang.IllegalStateException: DataBinder is already initialized with ConversionService` is threw. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Nice solution, but it is sad that if you have a request like "?page=" (so with an empty string as the parameter) `parse` is not called at all, so the page parameter will be set to null.

Answer (score 11):

The `ConversionService` is a nice solution, but it lacks a value if you give an empty string to your request like `?page=` The ConversionService is simply not called at all, but `page` is set to `null` (in case of `Integer`) or an Exception is thrown (in case of an `int`)

This is my preferred solution:

```
@RequestMapping
public void handleRequest( HttpServletRequest request ) {
    int page = ServletRequestUtils.getIntParameter(request, "page", 1);
}
```

This way you always have a valid int parameter.